# Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, restful-architecture, django-rest-framework

I have a method that grabs POST data that is formated in json format like this

```
[{"UserName": "alexgv", "Password": "secretpassword"}]
```

Here is the method

```
def Login(request, *args):
    data = request.DATA
    return Response(data)
"""
try:
    m = User.objects.get(UserName=request.DATA['UserName'])
    if m.password == request.DATA['Password']:
        request.session['member_id'] = m.id
        return HttpResponse("Testing")
except User.DoesNotExist:
    return HttpResponse("Your username and password didn't match.")
"""
```

I want to be able to take just one variable from that json POST. For example, maybe I just want to grab the UserName or Password. How would I do that? I have tried a variety of things but cant seem to get it to work, and I dont want to use request.POST.get because then that means I would have to send POST variables. BTW I am using this http://django-rest-framework.org/. I have read through the docs but cant seem to find anything in there. Any help is appreciated. What it returns right now is everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like so...

```
username = request.DATA['UserName']
```

Incidentally, you probably shouldn't be writing session based API login views yourself as it's easy to do wrong.

For APIs that provide AJAX style functionality the you have two good options:

- Login using a standard Django login, performed by the *user*, not performed by the API client.
- Use a credentials based authentication scheme, rather than session based, and perform the login using AJAX. For example the Djoser third party package is a great library including token-based login and other similar views... https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser

**Update** Also discovered https://github.com/JamesRitchie/django-rest-framework-sav which might be worth a look for AJAX session based authentication.

Comment: What's the reason behind advising against an API view that allows login? Given all the SPA JS options out there, I'd bet this is not uncommon among DRF users.

Comment: @jmq Updated with some better advice re standard session login, vs token based login.